# Merge two wordlists

Tags: c++, c, merge

I want to merge two wordlists into one file. All the duplicates must be removed. Each word is separated by a newline. I've searched for this kind of program but I can't find anything. Am I searching for the right thing? Is there a c/c++ implementation of this?

Comment: `cat wordlist1 wordlist2 | sort -u > onefile`

Comment: or better "sort -u wordlist1 wordlist2 > onefile"

Comment: @Chris: yes, better -- but I'm aiming for [an UUOC award](http://www.smallo.ruhr.de/award.html) :)

Answer (score 8):

```
// read input
std::ifstream in( file_path );
typedef std::set< std::string > wordlist_type;
wordlist_type wordlist;
std::string word;

while ( in >> word ) {
    wordlist.insert( word );
}

// repeat with other files to merge more wordlists

// now output to a new file
std::ofstream out( output_path );
for ( wordlist_type::iterator it = wordlist.begin(); it != wordlist.end(); ++ it ) {
    out << * it << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 3):

How big are the files.  If you can hold both of them in memory,
this is relatively simple using the STL:

```
std::vector<std::string> v(
        (std::istream_iterator<std::string>( ifile1 )),
        (std::istream_iterator<std::string>()));
v.insert(v.end(),
         std::istream_iterator<std::string>( ifile2 ),
         std::istream_iterator<std::string>());
std::sort( v.begin(), v.end() );
std::copy( v.begin(), std::unique( v.begin(), v.end() ),
           std::ostream_iterator<std::string>( ofile, "\n" ) );
```

or

```
std::vector<std::string> v1(
        (std::istream_iterator<std::string>( ifile1 )),
        (std::istream_iterator<std::string>()) );
std::sort( v1.begin(), v1.end() );
v1.erase( std::unique( v1.begin(), v1.end() ), v1.end() );
std::vector<std::string> v2(
        (std::istream_iterator<std::string>( ifile2 )),
        (std::istream_iterator<std::string>()) );
std::sort( v2.begin(), v2.end() );
v2.erase( std::unique( v2.begin(), v2.end() ), v2.end() );
std::set_intersection( v1.begin(), v1.end(),
                       v2.begin(), v2.end(),
                       std::ostream_iterator<std::string>( ofile, "\n" ) );
```

If they don't fit into memory, you'll probably have to sort each
file (using `system` to invoke your local utility), then do the
merge manually:

```
class FilterDuplicates
{
    std::ostream& myDest;
    std::string myLastOutput;
public:
    Outputter( std::ostream& dest ) : myDest( dest ) {}
    void write( std::string const& word ) const
    {
        if ( word != myLastOutput ) {
            myDest << word;
            myLastOutput = word;
        }
    }
};

ifile1 >> s1;
ifile2 >> s2;
FilterDuplicates out( ofile )
while ( ifile1 && ifile2 ) {
    if ( s1 < s2 ) {
        out.write( s1 );
        ifile1 >> s1;
    } else {
        out.write( s2 );
        ifile2 >> s2;
    }
}
while ( ifile1 ) {
    out.write( s1 );
    ifile1 >> s1;
}
while ( ifile2 ) {
    out.write( s2 );
    ifile2 >> s2;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <string>
#include <set>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::set<std::string> s;
    std::string word;
    while (std::cin >> word)
        s.insert(s);
    for (std::set<std::string>::const_iterator i = s.begin(); i != s.end(); ++i)
        std::cout << s << '\n';
}
```

usage:

```
cat input1 input2 | program > output
```

Comment: If you're going to require the use of the Unix toolkit: `sort -u input1 input2 > output` does the trick immediately:-).  (I sort of supposed Windows because he was trying to write a program to do it, which isn't necessary under Unix.)

Comment: @James: even Windoze has `type` and pipes - I think it just about manage this level of complexity...

Comment: Does the Windows sort utility have the equivalent of the Unix `-u` option?  Or does Windows have the equivalent of the Unix `unique`?

Comment: @James: Windows XP `sort` doesn't have any `-u` equivalent, and I can't find any unique equivalent but they might have called it something obscure.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to unix

```
cat file1 file2 | sort | uniq > file3
```

Comment: -1: not an answer. And [POSIX `uniq`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/uniq.html) does not eliminate duplicates: it only eliminates successive duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

something like this...

```
std::set<std::string> words;    
std::string word;

while(cin >> word)
  if (words.insert(word).second)
    cout << word;
```

EDIT: oops, too eager to simplify...